# Is it ok to redeclare private ivars in a subclass to make them accessible?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, subclass, foundation

When subclassing an Apple class that lists private ivars in the .h file, is it ok to redeclare those ivars in your own subclass in the class extension @interface inside your subclass .m file in order to make them accessible to your subclass implementation?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must bear in mind that declaring an instance variable in a subclass **does not redeclare an existing superclass instance variable with the same name**, regardless of the purported redeclaration being in the public interface or a class extension. Even if you use the same name, **it is a different instance variable**.

You can try this yourself. For example:

```
@interface Base : NSObject {
@private
    int _number;
}
@end

@implementation Base
- (id)init { self = [super init]; if (self) _number = 10; return self; }
- (void)logNumber { printf("base = %d\n", _number); }
@end

@interface Derived : Base
@end

@interface Derived () {
    int _number;
}
@end

@implementation Derived
- (id)init { self = [super init]; if (self) _number = 20; return self; }
- (void)logNumberDerived { printf("derived = %d\n", _number); }
@end

int main(void) {
    Derived *o = [Derived new];
    [o logNumber];
    [o logNumberDerived];
    return 0;
}
```

outputs:

```
base = 10
derived = 20
```

because `_number` in superclass is different from `_number` in subclass (extension). If you inspect the symbols in the binary output with `nm -a`, you’ll notice that the compiler generates two different symbols:

```
s _OBJC_IVAR_$_Base._number
s _OBJC_IVAR_$_Derived._number
```

Comment: Interesting. But presumably, if they are otherwise declared the same, your example indicates the one referenced in methods implemented in super will be the one declared in super. The one referenced in methods declared in subclass will be the one declared in subclass?

Comment: @uchuugaka Correct. Since the superclass ivar is private, the subclass cannot access that ivar and it only sees its own, different ivar. You need to make an extra effort (for example, using the Objective-C runtime API) to be able to access the superclass ivar.

Comment: Verified. I tested this with several variations, setters, getters & properties and sure as can be it is as you say. And this behavior could easily "seem" to work, when an ivar is an Object whose class is a parent class of the ivar I "think" I am redeclaring... (yes that is how I arrived at this question, but using an unsubclassable C type ivar is more clear!)

Comment: Categories too cannot do it. I have learned something. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I have found here the answer that exactly matches my own: http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2007/Feb/msg00939.html

> If they made it @private and not @protected you would have to assume
>   that it's for a reason. That reason could of course simply be that
>   it's prudent to make everything @private until you know a good reason
>   not to...
>
> That said, it could very definitively *not* be OK to access it
>   directly, even if it's technically possible.
>
> The safe thing to do is to re-do everything in your own class, while
>   petitioning the maintainer of the superclass to expose the
>   functionality you need in the public / protected interface.

Comment: Yeah. It's a bit old and not really official but sound thinking.